# renaming attachment file codeigniter

Tags: email, codeigniter, rename, email-attachments

can you help me for renaming attachment file on codeigniter without copy/move the source file?
this is my code

> $this->email->attach($filename);

can I rename a $filename to "new_file_name.pdf" ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter rename email attachement file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128250/codeigniter-rename-email-attachement-file)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. By using third parameter of same function.

```
$this->email->attach($filename, 'attachment', "new_file_name.pdf");
```

Although this functionality is only available in **CI v3.x**

To add this in previous versions you need to change the core email library or extend it. Try this link...
[adding rename functionality in CI v2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128250/codeigniter-rename-email-attachment-file)