# CodeIgniter rename email attachment file

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-2

I have CodeIgniter script for sending email with attachments.

```php
$this->ci->email->attach("/path/to/file/myjhxvbXhjdSycv1y.pdf");
```

It works great, but I have no idea, how rename attached file to some more user-friendly string?

Comment: `rename()` the file on the server before attaching the file.

Comment: i can't rename it on server dir. It must be do "on-fly" closely before send

Comment: You would have to modify CI's email library to get this to work.  It's not possible with the library as it stands, although it's a fairly easy modification.

Comment: Great, it works, thak you for your help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## CodeIgniter v3.x

This feature has been added since [CI v3](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.0.0/system/libraries/Email.php#L727-L736):

```php
/**
 * Assign file attachments
 *
 * @param   string  $file   Can be local path, URL or buffered content
 * @param   string  $disposition = 'attachment'
 * @param   string  $newname = NULL
 * @param   string  $mime = ''
 * @return  CI_Email
 */
public function attach($file, $disposition = '', $newname = NULL, $mime = '')
```

According to the [user guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#CI_Email::attach):

> If you’d like to use a custom file name, you can use the third
>   parameter:
>
> `$this->email->attach('filename.pdf', 'attachment', 'report.pdf');`

---

## CodeIgniter v2.x

However for CodeIgniter v2.x, you can extend the `Email` library to implement that:

1. Create a copy of `system/libraries/Email.php` and put it inside `application/libraries/`
2. Rename the file and add `MY_` prefix (or whatever you have set in `config.php`) `application/libraries/MY_Email.php`
3. Open the file and change the following:

**First:** Insert this at line **[#72](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/2.2.6/system/libraries/Email.php#L72)**:

```php
var $_attach_new_name = array();
```

**Second:** Change the code at line **[#161-166](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/2.2.6/system/libraries/Email.php#L161-L166)** to:

```php
if ($clear_attachments !== FALSE)
{
    $this->_attach_new_name = array();
    $this->_attach_name     = array();
    $this->_attach_type     = array();
    $this->_attach_disp     = array();
}
```

**Third:** Find the `attach()` function at line **[#409](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/2.2.6/system/libraries/Email.php#L409)** and change it to:

```php
public function attach($filename, $disposition = 'attachment', $new_name = NULL)
{
    $this->_attach_new_name[] = $new_name;
    $this->_attach_name[]     = $filename;
    $this->_attach_type[]     = $this->_mime_types(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $this->_attach_disp[]     = $disposition; // Can also be 'inline'  Not sure if it matters
    return $this;
}
```

**Fourth:** Finally at line **[#1143](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/2.2.6/system/libraries/Email.php#L1143)** change the code to:

```php
$basename = ($this->_attach_new_name[$i] === NULL)
    ? basename($filename) : $this->_attach_new_name[$i];
```

### Usage

```php
$this->email->attach('/path/to/fileName.ext', 'attachment', 'newFileName.ext');
```

Comment: Hashem's answer was great but you would have to override to core Email.php library so there's no need to prefix the copy with MY_

Answer (score 1):

This method is available also for CodeIgniter v1.7x

but you must not forget to modify also this function below to add `$this->_attach_new_name` to be also cleaned:

```
public function clear($clear_attachments = FALSE){
    $this->_subject     = "";
    $this->_body        = "";
    $this->_finalbody   = "";
    $this->_header_str  = "";
    $this->_replyto_flag = FALSE;
    $this->_recipients  = array();
    $this->_cc_array    = array();
    $this->_bcc_array   = array();
    $this->_headers     = array();
    $this->_debug_msg   = array();
    $this->_set_header('User-Agent', $this->useragent);
    $this->_set_header('Date', $this->_set_date());
    if ($clear_attachments !== FALSE){
        $this->_attach_new_name = array();
        $this->_attach_name     = array();
        $this->_attach_type     = array();
        $this->_attach_disp     = array();
    }
    return $this;
}
```